# Empty space in full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using Full Calendar and using slots to segment the day. In doing so, I end up with a large amount of empty space at the bottom of the calendar.

[image]

I have cut down from my application to reproduce on the basic sample from Full Calendar's website. You'll find the HTML below. You can see the large empty space beneath 7pm between there and the end of the page - that's what I want to remove.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    droppable: true,
    editable: true,

    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    slotDuration: '4:00:00',
    minTime: '07:00:00',
    maxTime: '23:00:00',
    timezone: 'local',
    allDaySlot: false,


    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [{
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2018-03-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2018-03-07',
        end: '2018-03-10'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2018-03-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2018-03-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2018-03-11',
        end: '2018-03-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2018-03-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2018-03-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2018-03-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2018-03-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Happy Hour',
        start: '2018-03-12T17:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Dinner',
        start: '2018-03-12T20:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2018-03-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2018-03-28'
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>


<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set [`height: "auto"`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/height) to get what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    droppable: true,
    editable: true,

    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    slotDuration: '4:00:00',
    minTime: '07:00:00',
    maxTime: '23:00:00',
    timezone: 'local',
    allDaySlot: false,
    
    // this line
    height: "auto",

    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [{
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2018-03-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2018-03-07',
        end: '2018-03-10'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2018-03-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2018-03-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2018-03-11',
        end: '2018-03-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2018-03-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2018-03-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2018-03-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2018-03-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Happy Hour',
        start: '2018-03-12T17:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Dinner',
        start: '2018-03-12T20:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2018-03-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2018-03-28'
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>


<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer produces the same empty space, but below the calendar, which might be desired.

However, I was looking for a way have the row height grow to use up more space.

```
    height: 'calc(100vh - 180px)',
    expandRows: true,
```